# Problems with ending memory write C#

Tags: c#, memory

I'm still learning C# and have the problem if I take out the if (m.Wparm.ToInt32() == 1005) then my keystroke works but I have to be able to end the continuous write again but it doesn't work with the break. Am I doing something wrong? It should only then stop writing the value to the memory. So I press NUM5 then he writes through and if I press again the NUM5 then he should stop writing in the memory because I then then value no longer Freezen would like.

```
 if (checkbox_zfreeze.Checked)
 {
     
     if (m.WParam.ToInt32() == 1005)
     {
         
         isNumpad5Enabled = !isNumpad5Enabled;
         if (isNumpad5Enabled)
         {
             module = swed.GetModuleBase("Game.dll");
             IntPtr pp = swed.ReadPointer(module, 0x00A12368, 0x58, 0x210, 0x224, 0x18);
             float fly = swed.ReadFloat(pp, +0xc3);

             float originalFlyValue = fly; 

       
             while (isNumpad5Enabled)
             {
                 
                 swed.WriteFloat(pp, 0xA0, originalFlyValue);

                 
                 if (m.WParam.ToInt32() == 1005)
                 {
                    
                     swed.WriteFloat(pp, 0xA0, originalFlyValue);
                     isNumpad5Enabled = false;
                     break;
                 }

                 
             }
         }
         else
         {
             
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: 1. What is `swed`? 2. There are two `if (m.WParam.ToInt32() == 1005)`, which one did you refer to? 3. According to the recent code, `while (isNumpad5Enabled)` and the second `if (m.WParam.ToInt32() == 1005)` are not necessary because these conditions are always true, do you miss any important information?

Comment: Swed is a library to read and write in memory. I have the so before when I press the first time on NUM5 activate it and write and when I press the second time on NUM5 finish writing and go out of the loop.